# How to run Powershell script with cmd

Tags: powershell, window, taskbar, keystroke

I have monitor which connects to PC with RDP. To prevent operator accessing desktop until machine runtime program is running I have disabled RDP connection until runtime program is up and running (kioks-mode was not an option unfortunately). When I enable RDP connection monitor log in to PC and runtime is open but because of log in windows taskbar is visible. I was wondering maybe I could use alt+tab keystroke to select runtime program and taskbar would go hidden.

What I am trying to do is simulate alt+tab keystroke combination with powershell. This part was easy and works great when manually ran on powershell.

But I would like to run this script with batch file or as scheduled task after log in.

I have tried multiple ways to try run this script automated but it is not working same as manually typing and executing commands. Fix for this or any other solution for selecting active program or hiding taskbar is also welcome.

```
//Keystroke combination script for powershell
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wsh.SendKeys('%{TAB}')
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am not too familiar with programming so I have tried to search and copy scripts that should work. Here is one I tried...   

PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Users\sakari.korpi\Desktop\PS.ps1""'}" -windowstyle hidden

Comment: Im wondering why you trying to start powershell within powershell. This should give the same result `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\sakari.korpi\Desktop\PS.ps1" -windowstyle hidden`

Comment: Actually now I took these .bat and .ps1 files and tested them on the machine they just might be working. I have failed testing these with my own PC but for now seems like these might be working after all! I will run some more test and update the results here.